# Failed to send a message to 65... - Message: element not interactable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

I'm trying to use 'alright' from https://github.com/Kalebu/alright
This is a python package developed to automate sending messages using WhatsApp.

However, I'm only able to make it work by sending the message one at a time, not in a loop.

Below is the code I use.

```
messenger = WhatsApp()
#send messages 
#looping through each number in list 'phone_contacts'
for num in phone_contacts:
    messenger.find_user('65{}'.format(num))      
    messenger.send_direct_message('65{}'.format(num)image_path,"Hi")`
```

I keep getting `element not interactable error`.

The observations are messages are indeed typed in WhatsApp, but the progress
stops there, manual clicking on 'send' button is needed for the message to be sent.

[image]

Not sure sure what went wrong, any help is greatly appreciated.

I tried to run the program. It is able to handle just single contact well.
But once it comes to multiple contacts each through a loop, there will be contacts
that are located but messages not sent, as well as messages typed, but not sent problem.